# Radiobuttonlist changes index on firefox reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, devexpress

I've an asp page with a DevExpress AspRadioButtonList. On Page_Load the SelectedIndex is set, based on a property variable. On ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChange some info is changed. All works as it's suppoused to up to this point.

In firefox, if a reload it's triggered, selected radio button circles throught all values. Any one has had a similar issue?

```
<dxe:ASPxRadioButtonList ID="rbl" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="radiobuttonlist">
    <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="secChecks" />
    <Items>
        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="Cms" Value="0" />
        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="News" Value="1" />
        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="Url" Value="3" />
        <%--<dxe:ListEditItem Text="Bussines" Value="2" />--%>            
    </Items>
</dxe:ASPxRadioButtonList>
```

On Page Load (a is an id parameter)

```
myClass s = new myClass (a);
            this.rbl.SelectedIndex = s.myProp;
            if (s.myProp== 3)
            {
                this.lbUrl.Text = s.Urlpublic;
            }
```

Javascript on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (radiobuttonlist.GetSelectedIndex() == 0)
    {        
        $("div.cms").show();            
    }
    else if (radiobuttonlist.GetSelectedIndex() == 3)
    {
        $("div.bussines").show();
    }
    else if (radiobuttonlist.GetSelectedIndex() == 1)
    {
        $("div.news").show();         
    }
    else if (radiobuttonlist.GetSelectedIndex() == 2)
    {
        $("div.url").show();        
    }
```

});

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gotten bit by this as well.  I found a solution on:

[www.ryancramer.com](http://www.ryancramer.com/journal/entries/radio_buttons_firefox/)

Basically, my problem occurred because I was dynamically adding in a flash object before my radio buttons.  My understanding is that this problem can occur when adding in input tags as well.  When I moved the radio buttons (markup) before the markup that I'm dynamically inserting, it worked fine.  If you don't want to move your markup, you can try adding an autocomplete="off" attribute to the surrounding form tag (ie. '').

Both of these solutions worked for me.  For more detail, check out the link.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! **cries from happines** didn't know what else to do to solve this. Thank you very much.